# is there anyway to calculate miles or meters to pixel on google map for calculating zoom level?

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, pixel, data-conversion

I have been searching on this thing from long time.
Is there any math formula to convert miles or meters to pixel for zoom level in google map? Any kind of help is appreciated. I am currently working for iOS.

Comment: take a look a this http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7430/what-ratio-scales-do-google-maps-zoom-levels-correspond-to

Comment: no luck. The thread came up with assumptions.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution from here https://gist.github.com/ryanhanwu/4dbcdbdf384f5a3cca1f
I re-wrote it for Swift 4 as below

```
let topLeft: CLLocationCoordinate2D = mapView.projection.visibleRegion().farLeft
let bottomLeft: CLLocationCoordinate2D = mapView.projection.visibleRegion().nearLeft
let zoom = mapView.camera.zoom
let lat = Double(fabs(Float(topLeft.latitude - bottomLeft.latitude)))
let metersPerPixel: Double = Double((cos(lat * .pi / 180) * 2 * .pi) * 6378137 / Double((256 * pow(2, zoom))))
```